# python kivy Boxlayout not organizing it's children

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating a simple Database-GUI and want to add two lines to a form. each line is a DataField-Object, and contains a label and a TextInput organised by a horizontal Boxlayout. up to here all fine.
The Form-Widget contains also a BoxLayout (Orientaton: "Vertical") organizing the two DataField-Objects by listing them up under each other, but it doesn't work...
My Question: WHY??? and how can I fix it?

dbgui3.py

```
from kivy import require
require("2.0.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty

class DataField(Widget):
    title = StringProperty()
    pass

class Form(Widget):
    b = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, *rec, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        for df in rec:
            self.b.add_widget(DataField(title=df))

class DbGui3(App):
    def build(self):
        return Form("hello", "world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DbGui3().run()
```

dbgui3.kv

```
<DataField>:
    text: txt.text

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width, 30
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.2,0.2,0.2
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Label:
            text: root.title
            size_hint: None, 1
            width: self.texture_size[0]

        TextInput:
            id:txt
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: print("text validated:" + root.text)
<Form>:
    b:b
    BoxLayout:
        id: b
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0.1,0.2,0.3
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
```

Comment: I also tried out Gridlayout with only one column and stacklayout orientation lr-tb, but nothing works, everytime all the cildren are displayed on the very bottom overlapping each other to 100%

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `Widget` as a base class for your `DataField` and `Form` classes. The `Widget` class does not take any notice of things like `size_hint`, `pos_hint`, and others. It is not intended to be a `Layout`. I suggest you use `BoxLayout` as the base for your `DataField` and some other `Layout` (perhaps `FloatLayout`) as the base class for `Form`. Using this suggestion, your class definitions could be:

```
class DataField(BoxLayout):
    title = StringProperty("example")

class Form(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

Then modifying your `kv`:

```
<DataField>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: 30
    orientation: "horizontal"

    Label:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size[0]*1.3, root.height
        text: root.title

    TextInput:
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: print(root.title)

<Form>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.width/2, root.height/2
    
        DataField:
            title: "hello"
    
        DataField:
            title: "world"
```

I think this will do what you want.

Comment: but the inner boxlayout of the datafield already works... only that of the form doesn't

Comment: and i tried out your option and got the same result